# SRVE0255E Webshere Admin Console

Tags: ibm, websphere

I can't open the administration console for Webshere. When I go to http://localhost:9043/ibm/console/ I get a SRVE0255E error.

```
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ApplicationName has not been defined
```

Normally it would mean the app has not started. But this is the admin console.

This came about after a server restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up reinstalling the admin console.